# EASY - Combinatorics - How many ways to build a word.

Tags: combinatorics

On how many ways can we build word with $N$ letters from multiset (each letter have to be used once and only once) that the word has all letters $B$ before letters $A$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the multiset consists only of copies of $A$ and $B$, there is of course one one way to make the required string.

If there are other characters in the multiset, you can find all possible arrangements of those other $N_O$ characters (call the count of possibilities $P_O$) and then extend that set by adding the unique solution of $N_{AB} = N-N_O$ characters in all possible insertions, giving

$$P_O{N \choose N_{AB}}$$

options